# Economic Clustering and need for (Dezentralized) Coordinators?

Tags: iri-node, coordinator, economics, decentralization

In CfB's recent [blog post on Economic Clustering and IOTA](https://medium.com/@comefrombeyond/economic-clustering-and-iota-d3a77388900), he looks at a possible future of IOTA and envisions two different types of IOTA clusters:

- **Cluster 0**: A a set of Full Nodes that are interchanging all
  transactions (just as today in the main net). Transaction are
  secured by means of a "decentralized coordinator".
- **Further clusters**: A set of Full Nodes in a spatially limited area,
  e.g. a town, with each Full Node processing all transactions from the
  town and from neighboring
  clusters (spatially seen), i.e. neighborhood towns. A few of these clusters, but definitely not all,
  may have a link to Cluster 0. Given this structure, IOTAs
  can be interchanged within spatially limited areas (= economic
  clusters), however, they cannot be interchanged between clusters that are separated by having multiple
  clusters in-between.

Based on this, I have three questions regarding the implementation of CfB's vision on Economic Clustering:

1. **Functionality of distributed coordinator in Cluster 0**:
   Would the
   "distributed coordinator" in Cluster 0 exist of multiple instances of
   basically the same Coo we are having today (in terms of its task
   when looking at the Coo as black box) which are run by different
   companies that are mutually trusting each other (as they can track
   what the other Coos are doing)?
2. **Need of coordinator(s) in other clusters**:
   In Cluster 0, IOTA transactions will be secured as of today in the main net (just by
   using the "distributed coordinator" instead of the central one we
   are having today). In the other clusters, IOTAs could be
   generated out of thin air, e.g. in exchange for real money, as long as people trust
   the issuing company. For example, a electric vehicle charging
   station operator could provide the service of charging electric
   vehicles in a certain cluster (i.e. a certain spatially limited
   area), and therefore issue its own IOTAs (which could be seen as a
   form of [colored tokens](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Colored_Coins)) in exchange for EUR.
   Outside of this cluster, these IOTAs will not be worth anything as
   the issuing party is only guaranteeing a counter value within the
   cluster. Given the nature of the Tangle, we still would need a
   coordinator for this cluster, is this true?
3. **Benefit of the Tangle when relying on coordinators**:
   In both cases, we still need one or multiple
   coordinators (which we may call a "decentralized coordinator").
   However, also when using a decentralized coordinator, we rely on some centralized instances. Given this fact, what are the benefit of
   using a DAG/the Tangle? Why not having a database table for managing all
   transactions and hence providing a balance per address? This
   database table could also be operated by different companies and
   each company could still say "yes, I approve that the transaction is valid" resulting
   in the same result: a balance per address, accepted by multiple
   companies. As we are not getting rid of the coordinators that are operated by some (few) central instances, what exactly are
   the major pros and cons of relying on the DAG structure?

Answer (score 2):

Since I am not CfB, I cannot guarantee that my answer aligns 100% with his vision but this is my understanding of it:

#### 1. Functionality of distributed coordinator in Cluster 0

Yes, exactly. The entities don't have to be companies, but it's very likely, that they will be.

#### 2. Need of coordinator(s) in other clusters

I don't know if Cluster 0 will need a Coordinator forever. If the honest transaction rate reaches a certain point, I think we could get rid of it entirely, but with current PoW (Proof of Work) and difficulty that point is just too high. *Maybe* Network bound PoW will change something about this but we know hardly anything about it.

For other clusters with "colored tokens", as you called them, we definitely need a Coordinator because/if the transaction rate is significantly lower.

#### 3. Benefit of the Tangle structure when relying on coordinators

1. **Permissionless**
   We don't need an API key or similar to send and receive Iotas. The only cost is the PoW. This can of course also be seen as a disadvantage since we have to do PoW.
2. **Ease of switching**
   It's easy to build an automated check into every full node similar to:

   > *If Coordinator A tries something malicious or stops working, don't trust it anymore. Trust Fallback Coordinator B instead. If Coordinator B tries something malicious or stops working, don't trust it anymore. Rely on weight only instead.*

   Since the Coordinator is not a central instance, even if it fails to do what it is supposed to, the network can continue working.
3. **We need a [`HAPPENED BEFORE`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happened-before) relation anyway**
   The Tangle has a very clear structure when it comes to which transaction happened before which transaction. If `TXA` is directly or indirectly referenced by `TXB`, we know that `TXA`→`TXB`. Therefore we also know that a Milestone `MS9` confirms all transactions that happened before it.
4. **Missing transactions**
   We know exactly, if we are missing a transaction or if our Tangle is [*solid*](https://iota.stackexchange.com/q/1102/10) because of the references. If one of our transactions points to `TXC` and we don't have a `TXC` in our database, we know that we have to request it from our neighbors.

Comment: I agree, that EC is at a very early stage and that there is a lot of research and defining to be done but I don't think remaining silent about it will solve the problem. What exactly do you mean by "IOTA should stop talking about it"? The community should stop discussing it? The Foundation shouldn't advertise with it? CFB should stop writing articles?

Comment: What's wrong with [that](https://www.iotanews.io/2018/06/20/exploring-the-economic-cluster-idea/)?

Comment: @AustinPowers A note on the "happened before" relationship: Guaranteeing this relationship is still possible when having multiple EC. By design, this relationship can be guaranteed within each Tangle. It is important to understand that the IOTA tokens in Cluster 0 are different to the "colored" IOTA tokens in other clusters. Moving a Cluster X colored IOTA token from Cluster X to Cluster Y requires an exchange service providing Cluster Y colored IOTA tokens. As each cluster operates an own Tangle and by relying on exchange services, the mechanism guaranteeing "happened before" is well defined.

Answer (score 0):

**Functionality of distributed coordinator in Cluster 0**

A distributed coordinator won't be the same as the centralized we know today. It is explain in the article :

> This software (i.e. distributed coo) does only one thing — it signals that a particular actor
>   has seen certain transactions and will accept them as legitimate ones
>   with some probability.

**Need of coordinator(s) in other clusters**

I don't see any reason to not have a distributed coordinator in other cluster (maybe we will see different clusters with different rules : centralized coo, distributed coo, permissioned cluster,... ?)

**Benefit of the Tangle when relying on coordinators**

*Distributed Coordinator**S*** . The S is important, it implies multiple entities, hopefully, in a permissionless tangle: anyone can run it. So it achieve full decentralization of the network. And  it don't relies on centralized instances. The term *distributed coordinator* shouldn't be assimilate to *centralized entity* ... it's instead a decentralized component.

Comment: The current coordinator signals that the actor "Iota Foundation" has seen certain transactions and everybody that trusts "Iota Foundation" will accept them as legitimate ones with a probability of near 100%. What am I missing?

Comment: As for Distributed Coordinator(s): The word "distributed" already implies multiple entities so I'd leave the "s" out unless you are really talking about multiple e.g. "2 distributed Coordinators in 2 different clusters" or "a main and a backup distributed Coordinator in the same cluster". Compare it to "a distributed database" or "a distributed OS" but I guess it's just semantics...